change @bhplugin/ng-datatable filter parameters
I use this package in my angular project .
I want to change text of filter items .
also I want to change filter text when column type is boolean.
please help me
thanks a lot
enter image description here
I change "bhplugin-ng-datatable.mjs" file in package but not work!!
